# Клавиатура в боте VK (Python, vk_api)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Возникла проблема с подключением клавиатуры в Python - Чат бота ВК:

клавиатура:

```py
keyboard = {
    "one_time": False,
    "buttons": [
        [{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"1\"}",
                 "label": "Бот 123"
            },
            "color": "positive"
        }],
        [{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                "label": "Cinema "
            },
            "color": "default"
        },
        {
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"3\"}",
                "label": "Развлечения "
            },
            "color": "default"
            }
        ]
    ]
}


keyboard = json.dumps(keyboard, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
keyboard = str(keyboard.decode('utf-8'))
```

На вывод сообщения:

```py
def new_message(self, message):

        # Привет
        if message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[0]:
            return f"Привет-привет, {self._USERNAME}!"

        # Погода
        elif message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[1]:
            return self._get_weather()

        # Время
        elif message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[2]:
            return self._get_time()

        # Пока
        elif message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[3]:
            return f"Пока-пока, {self._USERNAME}!"

        else:
            return "Не понимаю о чем вы..."
```

Пытаюсь подключить через "keyboard": keyboard, но после `:` пишет, что ошибка синтаксиса. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: В какой строчке? Или лучше весь вывод сообщения об ошибке целиком напишите.

Comment: в таком случае приложите код ошибки, не гадать же нам где она и о чем говорит

Comment: После строки return f"Привет-привет, {self._USERNAME}!" идет , "keyboard": keyboard , но идет ошибка после :, invalid syntax

Comment: @Amadea Пожалуйста, приведите весь вывод, начиная со слов `Traceback`. И код, в котором есть строка с ошибкой (`"keyboard": keyboard`).

Comment: Приведите именно тот вариант кода, на котором у вас ошибка и полностью текст ошибки!

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего из-за того что вы забыли, или неправильно поставили скобки.

Попробуйте так:

```
keyboard = {
"one_time": False,
"buttons": [
    [{
        "action": {
            "type": "text",
            "payload": "{\"button\": \"1\"}",
            "label": "Бот 123"
        },
        "color": "positive"
    }],
    [{
        "action": {
            "type": "text",
            "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
            "label": "Cinema "
        },
        "color": "default"
    }],
    [{
        "action": {
            "type": "text",
            "payload": "{\"button\": \"3\"}",
            "label": "Развлечения ",
        },
        "color": "default"
    }],
  ]
}
```